# angular1 with electron: ng-dblclick not working

Tags: angularjs, electron, angularjs-ng-click

I am using electron with angular 1.6.4.

I have a controller, in which I dynamically generate `li`. I want to bind a double click event on this list items, but I could not succeed.

```
function TheController($http, $scope, KeyService) {
  $scope.openItem = function(id) {
    console.log(id);
  }
  var key = KeyService.getLastKey();
  connectToBackend($http,key);

}

function connectToBackend($http, key) {
   $http.get(ENDPOINT).then(
      function(result) {
        //do some work
        document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += `<li draggable="true" ondragstart="itemDrag(event)" id=${theID} ng-dblclick="openItem(this.id)"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> ${result}</li><hr>`;
    }, 
    function(e) {
       //error 
    }
   );

}
```

If I double-click here, absolutely nothing happens - not even an exception.

If I use `ondblclick`, it works if I define `openItem` in `renderer.js`. But I'd rather like to have it defined inside `TheController`, to keep some order and to be able to access injected services.

Is this possible? Is the drag stuff maybe interfering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directly appended html wouldn't work until you compile it. You should manually compile it before injecting it into DOM tree.

```
document.getElementById("list")
.appendChild($compile(`
  <li draggable="true" ondragstart="itemDrag(event)" 
     id=${theID} ng-dblclick="openItem(this.id)">
        <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> ${result}
  </li>
<hr>`)($scope);
```

---

Generally doing DOM manipulation from directly controller is anti-pattern as it makes your controller code to more tightly coupled with view/html.

Rather I'd suggest you to use `ng-inlcude` directive and place custom template in `ng-template` script. So that it will available any time inside `$templateCache` of angular.

```
<script id="myCustom.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <li draggable="true" ondragstart="itemDrag(event)" 
     id="{{theId}}" ng-dblclick="openItem(id)">
        <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
        <div ng-include="ENDPOINT"></div>
  </li>
</script>
```

and then your html will look like below.

**Html**

```
<div id="list">

   ... Your content .. 

</div>
<div ng-include="'myCustom.html'"></div>
```

If you noted, I directly used `ENDPOINT` directly inside `ng-include` for the same to work, you have to do some additional setting

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    // Allow loading from outer templates domain.
    'http://somedomain.com/templates/**' //ENDPOINT domain should white listed here
  ]); 
});
```

Also `ondragstart` wouldn't call your controllers method, until you patch it up with angular wrapper directive. There are third-party library available out there, you could use any one of them.

Comment: Looks interesting. What if the  number of `<li>` are dyamic from the `connectToBackend()` call? Will it work with a `ng-repeat`?

Comment: @faboolous can you elaborate more on this.?